# how to select radio button on appium java if xpath is only available (no id and accessibilityid)

Tags: java, appium

How to tap/click on radio button without using absolute xpath via appium inspector?

[image]

here is the full details of the radio button:
[image]

[image]

how can I select 3rd or 4th radio button without using absolute xpath?